# How to read/write data from/to Azure Table using Hadoop?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-hdinsight

I'd like to have a hadoop job which read data from Azure table storage and write data back into it. How can I do that?

I'm mostly interested in writing data into Azure tables from HDInsight.